# OpenText LiveLink Search Metadata

Tags: java, search, opentext, livelink

I'd like to use the Java CWS web service to perform searches against Metadata stored in categories.

When I execute the `getFieldInfo` method the searchable fields in my categories are not listed. I'm trying to figure out the structure of the query expression for searching this info.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of OpenText/Livelink are you using?

Comment: Using Version 10.5

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this, the attributes for categories are not returned by the getFieldInfo method. They have special names in the format of:
attr_xxxxx_yyy, where xxxxx is the id of the category and yyy is a sequential number, incremented for each attribute in the category.